# Google Docs Spreadsheet, Send Email And Order Values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I created a form using google docs spreadsheet, and created a script that sends an email when the user fills the form:

```
function sendFormByEmail(e){

      var email = "AAA"; 
      var subject = "XXX";  
      var message = "";
      for(var field in e.namedValues)
        message += field + ' = '+ e.namedValues[field].toString() + "\n\n"; 

      var advancedArgs = {replyTo:e.namedValues['E-mail'].toString()};
      MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message, advancedArgs);


}
```

the script works,
but when it sends the email, data is not sorted as the fields of the form.

how can I modify my script to sort the values ​​as they are in the Spreadsheet (form)?

Comment: javascript's for(...in...) executes in arbitrary order.  Its documentation advice for not to use it if the order is relevant.

Answer (score 2):

You could get the columns order from the spreadsheet. Something like this:

```
function sendFormByEmail(e){

      var email = "AAA"; 
      var subject = "XXX";  
      var message = "";
      var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
      var headers = s.getRange(1,1,1,s.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
      for(var i in headers)
        message += headers[i] + ' = '+ e.namedValues[headers[i]].toString() + "\n\n"; 

      var advancedArgs = {replyTo:e.namedValues['E-mail'].toString()};
      MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message, advancedArgs);
}
```

Naturally, you have to change the sheet name `Sheet1` to your actual sheet name.
By the way, I have written a script that does this a lot more, maybe you want to check it out (if this is not only a programming exercise). It's called **FormEmailer** and you can find it in the Script Gallery and in its [site](http://sites.google.com/site/formemailer).

Comment: Be careful, the columns order may be diferent from the fields order, especially after editing the form and adding and deleting fields.

Comment: Agreed, but in such cases, it is easy to just go to the spreadsheet and sort the columns in the desired order. Since there's no API for Google Forms, the only way to know the actual order would be by analyzing the html.

Comment: Wait, you can't change the column's order, Forms will continue to write answers on the same positions, and you will have the fields mixed.

Comment: that is not true, have you tested it?

Comment: Well, I don't remember me testing it, but there's a warning about this in Google Docs help, https://support.google.com/docs/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139706&topic=1360904&ctx=topic, last paragraph.

Comment: Yes, it warns and all, but that's no how it works. I've tested it myself.

Comment: You want that I create a Google Form and move a column, to share the file with you? I must have understood it wrong, please clarify.

Comment: Only describe your test.  Are they exhaustive?  Or just a sample?  As far as I know, if you edit your form, delete some intermediate field, add another field at the end, may be this last added field will occupy the deleted field's column, and the columns order will be different than the field order.

Comment: Yes, they're exhaustive. I did this already on a dozens of forms, under different accounts. The script that I referred to on the post does it, and it has thousands of users worldwide. You may insert dummy columns between your columns. You may change the order, do whatever you want. The only thing that matters is the columns headers.

Comment: Yes, you're right, my mistake.  Agreed you can rearrange your column's order to match field's order.